# How to remove an element same like javascript

Tags: angular

Remove element but not working.Anyone can resolve this issue?

Comment: Why oh why would you need to manipulate the dom like this? ;) This is not recommended at all. Also unrelated, but, always include your code in your question. I demo to play with is GREAT, but links tend to die over time, so need to include relevant code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get elementRef and use Renderer2 to remove attribute (Renderer is deprecated)

```
@ViewChild('removeDisabled', {read: ElementRef}) removeDisabled:ElementRef;

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef,private rendd:Renderer2){ 

}

removeDisabledfn(){
  this.rendd.removeAttribute(this.removeDisabled.nativeElement, 'disabled');
}
```

and in template

```
<button  #removeDisabled disabled>Click Button</button>
```

Comment: How you want to remove disabled without having the disabled attribute in button.
If you want to set attribute use setAttribute.

Comment: change it to `this.rendd.setAttribute(this.removeDisabled.nativeElement, 'disabled', 'true');`

Comment: [setAttribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setAttribute) [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-kkksw3) It is working

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: While this is the correct answer to your question, you should almost never do this. You should be binding your attributes to properties in your component like @night_owl mentioned in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258903/3718246).

Answer (score 2):

So, this may not be the issue you are trying to solve, but it is generally best to use data bindings to apply/modify attributes.  Inside your component class:

```
export class AppComponent {
  buttonDisabled = false;
  toggleDisabled(){
    this.buttonDisabled = !this.buttonDisabled;
  } 
}
```

and in your html:

```
<button [disabled]='buttonDisabled'>Click Button</button>
<hr>
<button (click)="toggleDisabled()">Click To Disable</button>
```

The disabled attribute on the 'Click Button' button will follow the buttonDisabled boolean variable inside the component class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `Renderer2` API class's.

`removeAttribute(el: any, name: string, namespace?: string)` method of Angular. Create the instance of [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#removeAttribute) class inside your constructor component.

```
constructor(
   private elementRef: ElementRef,
   private renderer: Renderer2){ 
}

removeDisabledfn(){
  this.renderer.removeAttribute(<refrence_of_target_element>, <attribute_name>); // attribute_name in your case --> disabled (as string)
}
```